# Fibocom Modem Connect Internet AT Command Sequence

Tags: command, sequence, connect, at-command, carrier

I try to connect internet via AT commands with FIBOCOM modem. Sequence as follows. I got different techniques about it AT+COPS for example for carriers. But I guess I cannot go any further.

```
        _serialPort.Write("AT\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("ATZ\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("ATE0+CMEE=1;+CREG=2\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CPIN?\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CSQ\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CREG?\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CSQ\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=0\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CIMI\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CGSN\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CPMS?\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"infoteks\",\"0.0.0.0\",0,0\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CGQMIN=1,1,0,0,4,31\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        _serialPort.Write("ATD*99***1#\r");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

After this sequence done I got these report

```
CONNECT
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....
~^Y}#A!}!}!} }8}....

NO CARRIER
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMMAND IS 
AT+MIPCALL=1,"APN"/r

apn is acess point name if you give right name it will return ok
and after some time 20 sec max it will return connected ip address